# How to query to multiple folders in a directory at the same time with SPARKQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I´m trying to do a simple `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <TABLE1> SELECT * FROM <TABLE2>`
 the problem is that the table 2 is located in a specific directory in HDFS and the data is dispersed into 8 different folders.

Each folder contains partitions of the whole data and when I make a query to the main directory it shows me the following error:

```
INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 8
```

How can I access with the query to all the data?

thank you

Comment: Sounds like `table2` isn't properly partitioned. Can you post a `hdfs dfs -ls ` inside `table2`'s root directory?

Comment: What makes you think `INFO` indicates an error?

Comment: because after these it breaks out everything haha @DuduMarkovitz

Comment: Okey I will post the result @philantrovert thank you

Comment: And while "breaking out"(?) is there a real error message?